# Property of the floor function

Tags: calculus, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Given $u,v \in \mathbb{R}_{+}$, and let $n:=\lfloor v \rfloor$. where $u\in [0,1]$.

Is $\lfloor vu \rfloor =\lfloor nu \rfloor$ or $\lfloor vu \rfloor =\lfloor nu \rfloor+1$?

Edit: I missed the assumption that $u\in [0,1]$.

AugSB gave counterexamples, even a case where $\lfloor vu \rfloor =\lfloor nu \rfloor +2$.

However can i bound $\lfloor nu \rfloor$ somehow, like

$\lfloor vu \rfloor \in [\lfloor nu \rfloor ,\lfloor nu \rfloor +k]$, i hope $k=2$ should be enough.

Comment: The second one is false when $u$ and $v$ are integers.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions

Comment: Neither of them holds. Take, for instance, $v=7/2$ and try both for $u=3/10$ and $u=2/5$.

Comment: @AugSB thanks thats a good example. Can be say that $\lfloor vu \rfloor \in  [ \lfloor nu \rfloor,\lfloor nu \rfloor +2]$? Btw. i can't upvote your answer, which is really usefull for my question :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equality does not hold in every case. Take, for instance, $v=7/2$ and try both for $u=3/10$ and $u=2/5$.

However you can bound $\lfloor u v\rfloor$ in the interval $\big[\lfloor u n\rfloor, \lfloor u n\rfloor+1 \big]$, where $n=\lfloor v\rfloor$. Let $\{x\}=x-\lfloor x\rfloor$ be the fractional part of $x$. Then:

$$\lfloor u v\rfloor = uv - \{uv\}$$
$$\lfloor u n\rfloor = un - \{un\} = uv - u\{v\}-\{un\}$$

Therefore, it is enough to show that:
$$ u\{v\}+\{un\}-1 \le \{uv\} \le u\{v\}+\{un\}$$

For $u=0$ and $u=1$ it is clearly true, so let us assume that $u\in(0,1)$. Moreover, if $v$ is integer, the inequality holds too. Thus, let us assume $z\not\in\mathbb{Z}$. Then
$$ u\{v\}+\{un\}-1 \le \{u\{v\}+ un\} \le u\{v\}+\{un\}. $$
Thus it reduces to show that
$$ a+\{b\}-1 \le \{a+ b\} \le a+\{b\}, $$
where $a\in(0,1)$ and $b>0$. Try to follow from here.

Comment: For the left hand side we have $a+b-\lfloor b\rfloor -1 \leq a+b -\lfloor a+b\rfloor$ iff (multiplying with -1 and shorten a+b of both sides ) $\lfloor b \rfloor +1 =\lfloor a \rfloor + \lfloor b \rfloor +1 \geq \lfloor a+b \rfloor$ by the inequality property of the floor function. For the right hand side we have  $a+b-\lfloor a+b\rfloor\leq a+b-\lfloor b \rfloor$ iff $\lfloor a+ b\rfloor \geq \lfloor b \rfloor$,  where we multiplied both sides with -1 and shortened a+b out. Which is true also. Thanks for your help